# LSTM preditction give negative values

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting

I'm trying to forecast values from an univariate time-series with LSTM model but even if the time-series has only positive values, forecasted values sometimes are negative. I noticed that this happens when I change sequence size.
I don't know why this happens. Below the LSTM model.

```
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(units, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, 1)),
    Dropout(0.2),
    LSTM(units, activation='tanh', return_sequences=False),
    Dense(1)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

# Early stopping
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=20, verbose=1)

model.summary()
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=32, validation_data=(testX, testY), callbacks=[early_stop], verbose=2)

trainPredict = model.predict(trainX)
testPredict = model.predict(testX)
```

For example with a month of data with hourly timesteps I setted seq_size=24 and the model forecasts negative values.

Comment: Set the activation function of the output layer to "relu".